# Trouble getting started with SpringBoot and Gradle

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I am a new to Java, Gradle and Spring.

I setup a new project with the following gradle script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

When trying to build with the above script, I get the following errors:

```
E:\Projects\SpringAppTutorial>gradlew

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'SpringAppTutorial'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
    Required by:
        :SpringAppTutorial:unspecified
     > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
        > Could not parse POM http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.3.0.BUILD-20150531.081700-179.pom
           > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-tools:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
              > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-tools:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
                 > Could not parse POM http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-tools/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-tools-1.3.0.BUILD-20150531.081700-180.pom
                    > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-parent:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
                       > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-parent:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
                          > Could not parse POM http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-parent/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-parent-1.3.0.BUILD-20150531.081700-180.pom
                             > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
                                > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
                                   > Could not parse POM http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-dependencies-1.3.0.BUILD-20150531.081700-181.pom
                                      > Could not find org.springframework.data:spring-data-releasetrain:Fowler-RELEASE.
                                        Searched in the following locations:
                                            http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/data/spring-data-releasetrain/Fowler-RELEASE/spring-data-releasetrain-Fowler-RELEASE.pom
                                            http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/data/spring-data-releasetrain/Fowler-RELEASE/spring-data-releasetrain-Fowler-RELEASE.jar
                                            http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/data/spring-data-releasetrain/Fowler-RELEASE/spring-data-releasetrain-Fowler-RELEASE.pom
                                            http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/data/spring-data-releasetrain/Fowler-RELEASE/spring-data-releasetrain-Fowler-RELEASE.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 15.726 secs

E:\Projects\SpringAppTutorial>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using a release version of the spring-boot gradle plugin - your script is using a development snapshot version string of some kind.

i.e. try

```
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.3.RELEASE")
}
```

(from http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html)

Assuming that works, you should be able to get rid of this section also:

```
repositories {
   maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
   maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}
```

Comment: I had to remove the repo.spring.io/snapshot repos from the repositories list, and just have the repo.spring.io/release repo listed there. I also had to add mavenCentral() to the list of repos since it wasn't able to find other standard libs such as logging. Making both these changes fixed the build. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and as @skaffman suggests, I added version to my dependencies, it resolved.

```
implementation('org.springframework.session:spring-session:1.3.4.RELEASE')
 runtimeOnly('com.okta.spring:okta-spring-boot-starter:0.6.1')
 runtimeOnly('org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.4.RELEASE')
```